# Retain initial characters in file names, remove all remaining characters using powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

I have a batch of files with names like: `78887_16667_MR12_SMITH_JOHN_713_1.pdf`

**I need to retain the first three sets of numbers** and remove everything between the third "_" and "_1.pdf".

So this: `78887_16667_MR12_SMITH_JOHN_713_1.pdf`

Becomes this: `78887_16667_MR12_1.pdf`

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just use the 3rd "_" as the break as the third set of numbers sometimes includes 3 characters, sometimes 4 characters (like the example) and other times, 5 characters.

If I used something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem Default_*.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace...
```

...and then I'm stuck: **can I state that everything from the 3rd "*" and the 6th "*" should be replaced with "" (nothing)?** My understanding that I'd include ".Extension" to also save the extension, too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! While I'm sure we can help, this is not a code writing service. If you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20824928) your question to include the code that you tried, and the trouble you are having with it I'm sure that we can get it working for you.

Comment: Look at the use of the split function: $split = $filename.split('_')

Comment: Thank you @TheMadTechnician , I've edited it with what I hope is more helpful.

Comment: @OwainEsau - I'm not sure what to look at exactly. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-split` operator to split your name into `_`-separated tokens, extract the tokens of interest, and then join them again with the `-join` operator:

```
PS> ('78887_16667_MR12_SMITH_JOHN_713_1.pdf' -split '_')[0..2 + -1] -join '_'
78887_16667_MR12_1.pdf
```

`0..2` extracts the first 3 tokens, and `-1` the last one (you could write this array of indices as `0, 1, 2, -1` as well).

Applied in the context of renaming files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName {
    ($_.Name -split '_')[0..2 + -1] -join '_'
  } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Common parameter `-WhatIf` *previews* the rename operation; remove it to perform actual renaming.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Alberto_B; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

mklement0 has given you a good and working answer. Here is another way to do it using a regex.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match '(.*?_.*?_.*?)_.*(_1.*)') {
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($Matches[1..2] -join '') -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think I would have done `GCI|?{$_.Name -match '(^(?:.+?_){3}).*_([^_]*)$'}|%{Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($Matches[1..2] -join '')}` and utilized the pipeline rather than embed an `If` statement within the `ForEach-Object` loop. But that's just me.